# if Scanner Boolean statement with 2 nextInt() and hasNextInt() issue

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, java.util.scanner

i write this code but when my password is correct i have issue.please guide me.i am new at java coding

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordProjectQ {

    private static Scanner passwordInput;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        passwordInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        int builtInPassword = 3720118;

        System.out.println("Please enter your password:(just integer)");

        if(passwordInput.hasNextInt() && passwordInput.nextInt() != builtInPassword) {
            System.out.println("You entered the right format \nbut the password is WRONG!");
        }else if(passwordInput.hasNextInt() && passwordInput.nextInt() == builtInPassword) {
            System.out.println("Thanks,your password is correct");
        }else {
            System.out.println("WRONG format!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: How many times are you attempting to read the password when it is correct?

Comment: "i have issue" what makes you think so? Please see ["doesn't work"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)

Comment: I must type password correctly then press enter and again type the right password and enter then show "Thanks,your password is correct".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `hasNextInt()` and `passwordInput.nextInt()` only once to get the password, like this:

```
if (passwordInput.hasNextInt()) {
    if (passwordInput.nextInt() != builtInPassword) {
        System.out.println("You entered the right format \nbut the password is WRONG!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Thanks,your password is correct");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("WRONG format!");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.how can i close Scanner after first call if i want remain code unchanged?is it possible?

Comment: alternatively, store `passwordInput.nextInt()` in a variable

Comment: There is no need for an extra variable.

Comment: @houmanusf You can close the scanner when it is no longer needed. Don't close and reopen scanner again and don't use many scanner objects